# Running an Android app that has a dependency of another app in Google ARC

Tags: google-chrome-arc

Experimenting with Google Chrome ARC, I'm trying to run my application which has a dependency of another application (in particular, my application is using some library functions from OpenCV, and it needs the "OpenCV Manager" app to be installed on the device in order to work).

Is it possible to tell ARC that the 2 apps are connected (I got the APKs of both apps), or every app is entirely isolated and can't know about other apps?

Answer (score 0):

Your packaged APKs in your CRX file are isolated from those in any other CRX file, with the special exception of any APKs inside the ARC runtime CRX file.

You may be able to package the OpenCV manager APK in with your app (inside the same CRX file). It sounds like the license terms would allow it (but require a copyright notice). Since it would be bundled, you would lose out on automatic updates, which may or may not be a problem for you.

We definitely have integration tests which bundle two APKs together like this. However I'm not sure we have done much testing around having a service APK (like OpenCV Manger) with a normal app APK, so you may run into additional issues.

Note that ARC tries to start the main activity in the **last** APK installed (listed in the metadata file), so the OpenCV APK should be listed first.