# Run two APKs together - and have them detect each other

Tags: google-chrome-arc

What I'm attempting to do is run [Complete Linux Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid&hl=en) on a Chromebook through ARCwelder. The app runs as it should, but requires androidVNC and Android Terminal Emulator - both of which I've 'welded' to run and work as they should.

My problem is that the main app, `Complete Linux Installer`, will not detect the terminal app when it is running. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what it is. I'm beginning to think Google hasn't gone as far as allowing apps to communicate with each other through Chrome.

[Complete Linux Installer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL3TR.png)

If anyone knows why this happens, whether or not it's useless info, please let me know. There's not a lot on the web about welding APKs for Chrome - unless there's a forum dedicated to it that I've yet to discover. Also, I've read [29583906](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583906/running-an-android-app-that-has-a-dependency-of-another-app-in-google-arc), but it doesn't say exactly how to combine the apps. Am I missing something?

Comment: Each ARC app runs in its own virtual Android environment AFAICT. Outside of select scenarios (e.g., clipboard), it is as if the two ARC apps are on largely unrelated, separate hardware.

Comment: @CommonsWare In [29583906](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583906/running-an-android-app-that-has-a-dependency-of-another-app-in-google-arc), it says it's possible, but doesn't clearly explain how. Is that different from what I'm trying to do, or is there no hope for ARC?

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you're trying to do. I have no idea how to make that packaging work.

Comment: I have a theory about it. If it works, I'll report back in as clear detail as I can.

Comment: Just a small update: I gave up on this process. I apologize if anyone was waiting for a breakthrough, but I simply did not have the time to invest making the apps work together. There was a thing in the .json file where you include the apk, but that only crashed the app entirely.